# Would publishing and event queue work based on solution provided in Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 documentation?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, solution-architecture

I'm going through Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 architecture in http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreCommerce/DevOpsGuide/en-us/index.html#Concepts/c_M_ProductionDeployments.html.

I noticed that CM server doesn't have access to web database and CD server doesn't have access to Core database.

Would publishing work correctly in this case?

Would it still be possible to use event queues in this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that there is only high level diagram of the setup depicted in the documentation which is focusing mainly on Sitecore Commerce part and it's connections.

All connections which are relevant for Sitecore XP setup are still valid.

Therefore:

- Sitecore CM server should have access to master, web and core databases among other connections
- Sitecore CD server should have access to web and core databases among other connections

Nothing is changed here. You can follow normal publishing process as before.

Event queue can be used without any problem as you would do with pure Sitecore CMS solution. Sitecore Commerce is not affecting this setup.